# Scraping tweets from wapo gone awry

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

**Two issues.**

1. Goal etl a 3 columns csv with column headings of date, time, & tweet.
   My attempts at extracting the span text/time out of the li results in duplicating the span info inside the time and tweet columns. 
   It's my first week working with python, i've tried to replace() the tweet columns 'time' with "" but I end up removing both columns 'time' instances.
2. combining the columns together in-order or correctly mixing the data columns together as they appear. The code I write either results in 30,000 or 1000 lines. The correct csv file should be around 520 lines.

---

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests, urllib.request, csv
from urllib.request import urlopen


sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/politics/100-days-of-trump-tweets/?utm_term=.0c2052f6d858').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')

lists = soup.find_all('li', class_='visible')
dates = soup.find_all("li", attrs={"data-date": True})

tweet_data = ['date, time, tweets']

for li in   dates[1:]:
    date = li['data-date']
    tweet_data.append([date])

for list in lists[1:]:
    time = list.find_all('span', {"class": "gray"})[0].text
    tweets = list.text
    tweet_data.append([time, tweets])

with open('tweets_attempt_8.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(tweet_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. There are 504 lines in that page which you want to parse. You will get all of them with a csv output.

```
import csv ; import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('tweets_attempt_8.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(['date','time','tweets'])

    sauce = requests.get('https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/politics/100-days-of-trump-tweets/?utm_term=.0c2052f6d858',headers={"User-Agent":"Existed"}).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce,"html.parser")

    for item in soup.select("li.pg-excerpt.visible"):
        date = item.get('data-date')
        time = item.select("span.gray")[0].text
        title = item.text.strip()
        print(date, time, title[10:])
        writer.writerow([date, time, title[10:]])
```

Comment: Have you tried the script to find out whether it can do what you looked for?

Answer (score 2):

Here is code for which you needed to you out put...
I hope you are satisfy with this answers.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib2,csv
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

url='www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/politics/100-days-of-trump-tweets/?utm_term=.0c2052f6d858'

sauce = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
con = urllib2.urlopen(sauce)
data = con.read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

lists = soup.find_all('li', class_='visible')
dates = soup.find_all("li", attrs={"data-date": True})

tweet_data = ['date, time, tweets']

for li,list in zip(dates[1:],lists[1:]):
    date = li['data-date']
    time = list.find_all('span', {"class": "gray"})[0].text
    tweets = list.text
    tweet_data.append([date,time, tweets])

with open('/tmp/tweets_attempt_8.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
     writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
     writer.writerows(tweet_data)
```

[As you want the Out Put look at this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2rQC.png)